# Получить данные с сайта и записать их в файл PYTHON

Tags: python, файлы, requests, site

Задание :
Написать функцию, которая принимает в виде параметра целое число - количество цитат с сайта(https://forismatic.com/ru/).
Надо получить ровно столько не повторяющихся цитат с данными и сохранить их в csv файл
(имя файла сделать параметром по умолчанию).
Заголовки файла:
Author, Quote, URL. Если автор не указан, цитату не брать.
Перед сохранением в csv, записи отсортировать по автору (в алфавитном порядке)

Моя попытка :

```
import requests
import csv

# ####################################1
FILE_PATH = "(полный путь к файлу)FileCvs.cvs"
url = "https://forismatic.com/ru/"


# Написать функцию, которая принимает в виде параметра целое число - количество цитат

def choise_random_int(int):
    for number in range(int):
        params = {"method": "getQuote",
                  "format": "json",
                  "key": number,
                  "lang": "ru"}
        response = requests.get(url, params=params)
        result = response.json()
        for key in result:
            print(f"{key} ------ {result[key]}")


myData = [choise_random_int(3)]


# Если автор не указан, цитату не брать

def without_author(myData):
    om = [myData.get(key) for key in ('quoteText', 'quoteAuthor', 'quoteLink')]
    return om


# Отсортировать список в алфавитном порядке


def sortByAlphabet(quoteAuthor):
    return quoteAuthor[0]  # Ключом является первый символ в каждой строке, сортируем по нему


newList = sorted(om, key=sortByAlphabet)  # Каждый элемент передается в качестве параметра функции


# сохранить их в csv файл

def save_in_file_cvs(FILE_PATH):
    with open(FILE_PATH, "w", encoding="UTF-8"):
        writer = csv.writer(FILE_PATH)
        writer.writerows(newList)
```

Comment: и в чем вопрос?

Comment: в том, что решение не правильное , думала может кто-то посмотрит на мой код и исправит ошибки, а не будет писать с нуля )))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FILE_PATH = "(полный путь к файлу)FileCvs.cvs" (? может csv)

Comment: Я вам очень благодарна, вы даже не знаете сколько проблем мне решили )))